# Unable to disable suspend after closing laptop lid

Tags: laptop

I have two laptops running Ubuntu focal(20.04.5) and would like to keep the laptop
running after closing the lid.

I have successfully done the 'tweaks' setting outlined in
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-closelid.html.en

But, when I close the lid, both laptops enter sleep state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome uses logind to control powermanagement, so the best way is to alter a file with

`sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Go to the line with **HandleLidSwitch**, ensure there is no `#` in front of that line, otherwise remove it.

Change that line to `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` , save the file and reboot. Should work now.

Other settings of this this switch are described  [here](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/lid-close-behavior-ubuntu-20-04/)